# Select one row with values and remain same rows with null values

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I have data like this :

```
Date_time OS       Login    Action    Download  Action_detail      Download_detail
09-09-19  Android  User_id  Download  50        Download - Games   20
09-09-19  Android  User_id  Download  50        Download - App     15
09-09-19  Android  User_id  Download  50        Download - Music   30  
09-09-19  Android  User_id  Download  50        Download - Others  20
09-09-19  Android  Guest    Download  20        Download - Games   20
09-09-19  iOS      User_id  Download  10        Download - Others  15
09-09-19  iOS      Guest    Uninstall 15        Download - Games   20
09-09-19  iOS      Guest    Uninstall 15        Download - App     5
10-09-19  iOS      Guest    Uninstall 20        Download - App     15
10-09-19  iOS      Guest    Uninstall 20        Download - App     10
```

is there anyways I can have the query with return like this :

```
Date_time OS       Login    Action    Download  Action_detail      Download_detail
09-09-19  Android  User_id  Download  50        Download - Games   20
09-09-19  Android  User_id  Download  (null)    Download - App     15
09-09-19  Android  User_id  Download  (null)    Download - Music   30  
09-09-19  Android  User_id  Download  (null)    Download - Others  20
09-09-19  Android  Guest    Download  20        Download - Games   20
09-09-19  iOS      User_id  Download  10        Download - Others  15
09-09-19  iOS      Guest    Uninstall 15        Download - Games   20
09-09-19  iOS      Guest    Uninstall (null)    Download - App     5
10-09-19  iOS      Guest    Uninstall 20        Download - App     15
10-09-19  iOS      Guest    Uninstall (null)    Download - App     10
```

the column Download number is unique number of Download action,
in the end, what I want is to summary it with unique date_time, OS, Login, Action as slicer.

Comment: Do you try put where condition like this "WHERE download IS NOT NULL OR download is NULL" ?

Comment: no, the first one is my data, and the second is the result I wanted. I wanted to make it as null for repeating data from Date_time, OS, Login, Action and remain the same for Action_detail and Download_detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LAG function to get your required result as below-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=870b0a87c2aeaf55774ab4be35ca7de2)

```
SELECT Date_time,OS,Login,Action,Download,Action_detail,Download_detail, 
CASE 
    WHEN Download = LAG(Download,1) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL FROM DUAL)) THEN NULL
    ELSE Download
END New_Column
FROM your_table
```

> There is an issue with ORDER for WINDOW function as you can see I have used "SELECT NULL FROM DUAL" to keep the normal ORDER of data. But this will not confirm that the Ordering of data will be always same in this way. If you have any column in the table can be use for Ordering, that will be the correct approach.

Comment: I try to modified a little bit from your suggestion and it helps. Thanks!